# How do different stages attach to each other?

Tags: rockets, design-alternative, stages

I started learning about rockets recently, and while searching for information, I found some ways that different stages separate, but I wandered if it was possible that they could reattach to a different one, so that they could refuel in the space or even in another planet.

If that was the case, how would they do it, and has it been done before ?

Thank you

Comment: Reattaching a stage would be very difficult compared to a separation and as far as I know was never done.

Comment: What you're referring to would be a "docking port".  Stage couplings are generally designed for detatchment only, and often are single use components.

Comment: In spirit, this is a bit like the SpaceX plan to launch Starships and refuel them in orbit. I wonder if they've done a side-by-side comparison of transferring fuel vs. transferring whole stages.

Comment: Docking in space goes back to the beginning, as it was first tested during the Gemini program as it was required for Apollo. https://airandspace.si.edu/multimedia-gallery/3992hjpg